# MacBook Pro Internal speaker has just stopped to sound (but startup chime sounds)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, speakers

The internal speaker of my MacBook Pro suddenly stopped sounding. I just tried PRAM reset, but it doesn't work.

The audio works when I plug in earphones and goes when plug out.

I don't think, it's a hardware problem, because, the startup chime sounds when I start the computer. (correct me if I am wrong in this point).

Anyone have any idea why this may happen and how to fix it?

Image : It also disappeared from the output list:
[image]

> **Not a hardware problem:** Some people are referring this as a duplicate of a post, which has a hardware issue, I already mentioned above, the sound works for me while startup (startup chime). So it's not a hardware issue. (Pls explain in comment, if I am wrong in this point, other than marking as duplicate without any will to help).

Comment: @Tetsujin, that one is a hardware problem, for my case, the sound works for "startup chime", so not a hardware problem.

Comment: When you connect headphones, your internal speakers are disabled. However, if you are seeing the image you attached in your question *without* headphones plugged in, I would believe your logic board might be the source of the issue. Have a look at [this question and its answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48534/is-it-possible-to-play-sound-through-both-the-headphone-jack-and-my-internal-spe) for some possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, I see the image without any headphone connected. You suggested to question which asks for playing sound in both headphone and speaker. Did you really wanted to suggest this post or another one?

Comment: Day by day Stack exchange network looks funny to me! See the question / answer which is referred as a duplicate of this. I can't do anything here except tearing my hairs myself.

Comment: Luckily my speakers started working suddenly. Don't know what fixed it. Mac behaves really strange sometimes. Thanks who tried to help (by marking as duplicate).