# How can I send my computer's audio to multiple outputs?

Tags: audio, soundflower

I'm sending my system's audio to [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower), but I want to send it to my headphones at the same time. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Open Audio MIDI Setup from **Applications > Utilities**.
2. Click the + button in the bottom left corner and select "Create Multi-Output Device".
3. Check “Built-In Output” (this may already be checked) and the Soundflower output of your choice.
4. Right-click (or control-click) the device you just created and select “Use this device for sound output”.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Worth noting that device aggregation doesn't work for all devices. It's manufacturer-dependent. For example: Apogee doesn't support aggregation with any of their devices. Also, this wouldn't necessarily let you route audio to multiple devices simultaneously. If you combined 2 2x devices to a 4x device and played a stereo stream on that new aggregate, you'd only near the output on 2 of the 4 channels available on that aggregate.

Comment: This worked for my bluetooth headphones, too.. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

That's where the Soundflowerbed application comes into play. It lets you select out of which output you would like to play the sound that the rest of the system is feeding into sound flower.

[image]