# How to use laptop mic instead of headphone mic by software?

Tags: macos, big-sur, microphone

How can I use my macbook microphone even when trrs headphones are connected, by only changing software — without having to fiddle around with any hardware, converters, the physical connection, as all of the answers here suggest to: [Internal Mic Option Disappears when using Apple Earbuds](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/93559/150109)

How can I change my system to always use laptop microphone?

Comment: Try using the built-in Audio MIDI Setup app. Step 3 on [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/audio-midi-setup/set-up-audio-devices-ams59f301fda/mac) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app that manages sound inputs and outputs for you, such as SoundSource. It saves your settings so you only have to change your preferred output method once.
Or you can use the Sounds pane in system preferences, under input you can click the mic you want to use and Mac should remember that choice as well.