# Make "Internal Speakers" a permanent option in sound options on the menu bar

Tags: audio, headphones, speakers

Sometimes I use a headset with my iMac, but I often need to switch between both. Unfortunately, I need to unplug the headset every time to do this. This is a hassle, because the iMac is located far back at the table and is surrounded by documents and other things.

Back when I had Windows, I could just switch between "Internal Speakers", "Headset" and every other sound-system that was connected to the PC.

When using the options in the sound icon in the menu bar, the "Internal Speakers" option disappears as soon as the Headsets are plugged in.

How can I make them stay? I really would like to choose between both outputs without unplugging the headset.

edit: no workaround like in "Use internal speakers with others plugged in", just making "Internal Speakers" a permanent option without alternative solution

Comment: Also - that question I linked to has a lot of wrong answers. I believe your only option is to get USB hardware and plug your headphones into that. Perhaps someone can find a workaround in software, but it's been a long, long time since people have asked for this and we haven't gotten a single answer that says it's possible.

Comment: @bmike Exactly. I already read the answers in that (old) question. It seems like their is no real solution, just hack-ish work arounds. I hope someone will provide a software solution someday, or even better apple should fix this basic thing in the next **OS X** update

Comment: I doubt it is something Apple has forgotten. You might file a bug or feedback if you want to be certain they are aware of how it impacts you, but my guess is they will close it as "works as designed". My impression is this is an intentional design decision and [not something we can hack / over-ride](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/124085/5472).